# Reading from a file with .equalIgnoreCase() method

Tags: java, ignore-case

I need to add ignoreCase while reading a name from a file provided..still a beginner so where am i supposed to add the .equalsIgnoreCase() method? please help!

```
    while(inputFileBoy.hasNext())
    {
        male.add(inputFileBoy.nextLine());
    }
    while (inputFileGirl.hasNext())
    {
        female.add(inputFileGirl.nextLine());
    }
    Boolean ifMales,ifFemales;
    ifMales=ifFound(male,name);
    ifFemales=ifFound(female,name);

    //if statement to check
    if(ifMales || ifFemales)
    {
        System.out.println("Name *"+ name+ "* is POPULAR");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Name *"+ name+ "* is NOT POPULAR");
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by ignore case while reading a name? Are you trying to compare the names from the file against some other strings because I don't see any other strings in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could re-write the ifFound function to check if an element in the collection being passed as the first parameter `.equalsIgnoreCase(name)` and return true.

This should not require much editing and would probably just involve replacing the `.equals(name)` function in ifFound with `.equalsIgnoreCase(name)`.